# Unquote the result of a function defined by a macro

Tags: macros, elixir

I have the following definition of my macro

```
defmacro defverified(sign, body) do 
  {name, _, [param]} = sign
  quote do
    def unquote(name)(unquote(param)) do  
      unquote(param) = verify! param
      unquote(body)
    end
  end
end
```

Were `verify!/1` returns its paramters if it is verified as a correct parameter

And my function is defined as follows

```
defverified toto(p) do 
  IO.inspect p 
end
```

And the inspection of the content of `p` is correct but the return of the function is a quoted form of my variable.

```
iex(3)> res = Toto.toto(1)
1
[do: 1]
iex(4)> res
[do: 1]
```

Is it possible to have an unquoted form for the return of my function or should I unquote it manually?
I expect the following output of my function

```
iex(3)> res = Toto.toto(1)
1
1
iex(4)> res
1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because the `do`...`end` construct is a peculiar piece of syntactic sugar.  For example, this:

```
def toto(p) do 
  IO.inspect p 
end
```

is equivalent to:

```
def toto(p), do: IO.inspect p
```

which, because keywords at the end of an argument get passed as a keyword list, is equivalent to:

```
def(toto(p), [do: IO.inspect(p)])
```

Since your `defverified` macro only expects a `do` block and no other keyword parameters, we can explicitly match out the actual body:

```
defmacro defverified(sign, [do: body]) do 
...
```

Before doing this, the last form in the `toto` function would literally be:

```
[do: IO.inspect param]
```

which would call `IO.inspect` as expected but then return a keyword list instead of a plain value.

Comment: You beat me to it by a minute :) By the way, the square brackets are not necessary in `(sign, [do: body])`.